# Tokenizing an ArrayList attribute of a constructor

Tags: java

So I have this Java Class with the following attributes with setters and getters etc:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

//Student attributes
protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;
protected String major;
protected String idNo;
protected ArrayList<String> courseTaken;
protected int credits;
protected double grade;

public Student(){

}
//constructor
public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String major, String idNo, ArrayList<String> courseTaken, int credits, double grade)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.major = major;
    this.idNo = idNo;
    this.courseTaken = courseTaken;
    this.credits = credits;
    this.grade = grade;
}
```

And in my Main.java I want to read a txt file, tokenize to my Student class like so:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        // create a Buffered Reader object instance with a FileReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

        // read the first line from the text file
        String fileRead = br.readLine();

        // loop until all lines are read
        while (fileRead != null)
        {
            // use string.split to load a string array with the values from each line of
            // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
            String[] tokenize = fileRead.split(",");

            // assume file is made correctly
            // and make temporary variables for the seven types of data
            String tempFirstN= tokenize[0];
            String tempLastN = tokenize[1];
            String tempMajor = tokenize[2];
            String tempIdNo = tokenize[3];
            String tempCourse = tokenize[4];
            int tempCredits = Integer.parseInt(tokenize[5]);
            double tempGpa = Double.parseDouble(tokenize[6]);


            // create temporary instance of Student object
            // and load with three data values

            /**this is the problem!!
             *
             * Student takes in all tokens as Strings when tempCourse is an ArrayList<String>
             *
             **/
            Student tempStudent = new Student(tempFirstN, tempLastN, tempMajor, tempIdNo, tempCourse, tempCredits, tempGpa);

            // add to array list
            students.add(tempStudent);
```

Edit:  The text file I'm suppose to read looks like this, where -999 is a "stop read and go to the next data" limiter.

```
Jones,Mary,903452
4342,2.5,A
3311,C
-999
Martin,Joseph,312345
4598,3,C
1122,3
-999
```

I thought this was possible.  Obviously it's not.  How can I do this?

---

From comment in code:
this is the problem!!
Student takes in all tokens as Strings when tempCourse is an `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: `"I thought this was possible. Obviously it's not."` -- based on what information? Most depends on the structure of the text file, something you've not yet shown us.

Comment: Ah part of your question is buried in comments -- please don't do that. Put the main meat of the question out for all to see.

Comment: How is tempCourse stored in the file? Is it a text file? Please make your question more complete so that it is possible to answer.

Comment: Your code and your file don't appear to match at all. Each data element is composed of multiple lines and yet you appear to be trying to parse it as if it's all on a single line -- why?

Comment: That's probably the problem.  I just started coding this last night when I encountered the error.  I'll look for another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your parsing code doesn't match the data in the file at all. You appear to be trying to read all the data as if it is on one single line, and then split it as if this single line contains 7 tokens:

```
String[] tokenize = fileRead.split(",");

String tempFirstN= tokenize[0];
String tempLastN = tokenize[1];
String tempMajor = tokenize[2];
String tempIdNo = tokenize[3];
String tempCourse = tokenize[4];
int tempCredits = Integer.parseInt(tokenize[5]);
double tempGpa = Double.parseDouble(tokenize[6]);  // !! 7 tokens !!
```

But your file isn't constructed like this at all:

```
Jones,Mary,903452
4342,2.5,A
3311,C
-999
Martin,Joseph,312345
4598,3,C
1122,3
-999
```

Rather it appears that each Student in the file representation contains several lines, a variable number in fact, that the first line contains just 3 tokens, the second (perhaps) 3, and then it's anyone's guess what the next lines show.

To solve this you must fully understand the file structure and then change your parsing code accordingly, including using an inner loop to read the text until "-999" appears.

Answer (score 1):

`tempCourse` is a String, but in the constructor you expect an `ArrayList<String>` for courseTaken. Obviously this will not work (there is no autoconversion from individual single objects to ArrayLists for those objects).

You would either have to make this field and constructor argument a String (thus having exactly one course for each Student), or split the tempCourse token into individual Strings (using another, additional delimiter, e.g. a semicolon), fill them into an ArrayList and pass that ArrayList to the constructor.